# URLSession delegate is not working on swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

This code is working fine on Swift version 3, I'm not able to make it work on Swift 4

```
func rest() {
        let path = "https://localhost:8443/someservice"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)
            if let c = json["content"].string {
                print(c)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }
```

Comment: You will get faster and more accurate answers (and, depending on the whim of readers, fewer downvotes) if you explain the problem that you're seeing. "Not working" is never specific enough. There is an unbounded quantity of ways that any piece of code can go wrong, and it's hard in most cases to figure it out just reading it (especially if it used to work). You will save everyone time and energy by including compiler errors or runtime errors in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You may need latest syntax

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                task: URLSessionTask, 
          didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, 
   completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Delegate method is right for below swift 4.0 version but it's wrong for swift 4.0 and higher.**

Here is working code, You need to use like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,URLSessionDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
         completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }
}
```